# Cannot scrap the contents of a table. I get some sort of call to a database instead. How to get the contents that I can see with Python BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When using BeautifulSoup to scrap a table from https://egov.uscis.gov/processing-times/historic-pt, instead of getting the values that can bee seen in the content of the table, I get what seems to be a call from some sort of database:

```
table = webpage.select("table.records")
table
df = pd.read_html(str(table), na_values=0)[0]

df
```

```
Form    Form Description    Classification or Basis for Filing  FY 2017 FY 2018 FY 2019 FY 2020 FY 2021 FY 20225
0   ${data.FORM_NAME}   ${data.FORM_TITLE_EN}   ${data.FORM_DESC_EN}    ${data.FY14}    ${data.FY15}    ${data.FY16}    ${data.FY17}    ${data.NAT_AVG_MONTHS}  ${data.FY22}
```

When I inspect the table  with F12 I can see several <tr with the content that I wish to scrap; however, when I look at the source code, what I see is what I suspect is a call to a database:

```
<tbody class="recordsBody">
<tr v-for="data in histFormsData">
<th scope="row" style="border-right:1px solid black; font-weight:bold">${data.FORM_NAME}</th>
<th scope="row">${data.FORM_TITLE_EN}</th>
<th scope="row" style="border-right:1px solid black">${data.FORM_DESC_EN}</th>
<td style="border-right:1px solid black; text-align:center">${data.FY14}</td>
<td style="border-right:1px solid black; border-right:1px solid black;text-align:center">${data.FY15}</td>
<td style="border-right:1px solid black; text-align:center">${data.FY16}</td>
<td style="border-right:1px solid black; text-align:center">${data.FY17}</td>
<td style="border-right:1px solid black; text-align:center">${data.NAT_AVG_MONTHS}</td>
<td style="text-align:center">${data.FY22}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

This is the code I used to get request the webpage:

```
#Load webpage content

r = requests.get("https://egov.uscis.gov/processing-times/historic-pt")

#Convert to beautiful soup object

webpage = bs(r.content)

print(webpage.prettify())
```

What can I do to get the row content that can be seen in the page? I am new to web scraping and I was not able to find my question online.

Thanks in advance.

I tried importing the required packages, request the webpage, and use pandas to get the table:

```
#Import important packages
import requests # this one is for accessing webpages
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs #scraping tool
import pandas as pd #pandas

#Load webpage content
r = requests.get("https://egov.uscis.gov/processing-times/historic-pt")

#Convert to beautiful soup object
webpage = bs(r.content)
print(webpage.prettify())

#Scraping table with pandas
table = webpage.select("table.records")
table
df = pd.read_html(str(table), na_values=0)[0]
df
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is loaded from different URL so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it, try:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://egov.uscis.gov/processing-times/historical-forms-data"

df = pd.DataFrame(requests.get(url, verify=False).json())
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   FORM_NUMBER FORM_NAME FORM_NAME_ES                                                                             FORM_TITLE_EN                                                                                 FORM_TITLE_ES                                                                                                                      FORM_DESC_EN                                                                                                                                                  FORM_DESC_ES  FY14  FY15  FY16  FY17 NAT_AVG_MONTHS  FY22
0          I90      I-90         I-90                                            Application to Replace Permanent Resident Card                                     Solicitud para Reemplazar Tarjeta de Residente Permanente                                                                                          Initial issuance, replacement or renewal                                                                                                                       Emisión inicial, reemplazo o renovación   6.8   8.0   7.8   8.3            5.2   1.2
1         I102     I-102        I-102                 Application for Replacement/Initial Nonimmigrant Arrival/Departure Record             Solicitud para Reemplazar o Registro Inicial de Entrada / Salida de No Inmigrante                                                                                    Initial issuance or replacement of a Form I-94                                                                                                             Emisión inicial o reemplazo de un Formulario I-94   4.9   3.9   3.3   3.9            4.0   7.8
2         I129     I-129        I-129                                                        Petition for a Nonimmigrant Worker                                                          Petición de Trabajador No Inmigrante                                                                                             Nonimmigrant Petition (Premium filed)                                                                                                     Petición de No Inmigrante (con Procesamiento Prioritario)   0.4   0.4   0.4   0.4            0.3   0.3
3         I129     I-129        I-129                                                        Petition for a Nonimmigrant Worker                                                          Petición de Trabajador No Inmigrante                                                                                         Nonimmigrant Petition (non Premium filed)                                                                                                     Petición de No Inmigrante (sin Procesamiento Prioritario)   3.4   3.8   4.7   2.3            1.8   2.3
4        I129F    I-129F       I-129F                                                              Petition for Alien Fiancé(e)                                                        Petición de Prometido(a) Extranjero(a)                                                                                                               All Classifications                                                                                                                                     Todas las Clasificaciones   3.6   6.5   5.2   4.6            8.0  12.1
5         I130     I-130        I-130                                                               Petition for Alien Relative                                                               Petición de Familiar Extranjero                                                                                                                Immediate Relative                                                                                                                                            Familiar Inmediato   6.5   7.6   8.6   8.3           10.2  10.3
6         I131     I-131        I-131                                                           Application for Travel Document                                                               Solicitud de Documento de Viaje                                                                                                           Advance Parole Document                                                                                                                               Documento de Permiso Adelantado   3.0   3.6   4.5   4.6            7.7   7.3
7         I131     I-131        I-131                                                           Application for Travel Document                                                               Solicitud de Documento de Viaje                                                                                                                   Parole in Place                                                                                                                             Permiso de Permanencia en el País   2.5   3.3   3.3   4.8            4.9   4.7
8         I131     I-131        I-131                                                           Application for Travel Document                                                               Solicitud de Documento de Viaje                                                                                                                   Travel Document                                                                                                                                            Documento de Viaje   4.2   2.9   2.8   4.0            7.2  10.6
9         I140     I-140        I-140                                                      Immigrant Petition for Alien Workers                                                  Petición de Trabajador Inmigrante Extranjero                                                                                                Immigrant Petition (Premium filed)                                                                                                        Petición de Inmigrante (con Procesamiento Prioritario)   0.4   0.3   0.3   0.3            0.4   0.3
10        I140     I-140        I-140                                                      Immigrant Petition for Alien Workers                                                  Petición de Trabajador Inmigrante Extranjero                                                                                            Immigrant Petition (non Premium filed)                                                                                                        Petición de Inmigrante (sin Procesamiento Prioritario)   7.3   8.9   5.8   4.9            8.2   9.3

...
```

Comment: That seems to be the data, except that it is missing the columns from 2018 up to 2021. Also, how did you find out this was the url? Thanks!

Comment: @ChristianSánchez The data should be there - the server returns incorrect column names (but the data is correct). You can observer all requests the page is doing in Developer Tools -> Network Tab in your browser.

Comment: You are correct! Thanks a lot, this will help me plenty.